# Codeigniter active records insert query with single quotes

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert, escaping

I am trying to add a single record to a database table using codeigniter active records. The original data is parsed from XML and I have tested that the data is stored present and correct in its respective variable names.

The data is passed from the controller to the view like this:

```
$data['questionId'] = $question['id'];
$data['answerText'] = $question->answer;
$q = $this->mobile_user_model->save_actual_answers($data);
```

And the model insert function looks like this:

```
function save_actual_answers($data) {
    $insert = array(
        'answerText' => $data['answerText'],
        'responseId' => $data['responseId'],
        'questionId' => $data['questionId']
    );
    $q = $this->db->insert('actual_answers', $insert);
    return $q;
}
```

The problem I am having is that codeigniter is not automatically adding single quotes to the string value supplied for answerText. When I run the function, I get this error:

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column 'Dan' in 'field list'
INSERT INTO `actual_answers` (`answerText`, `responseId`, `questionId`)
VALUES (Dan, 12, 7)
```

This tells me that the value for answerText (in this case the value Dan) is trying to be entered into the table by codeigniter without the single quotes. However, if I hardcode the single quotes myself and append them to the answerText data, like so:

```
'answerText' => "'" . $data['answerText'] . "'"
```

the query runs successfully, but the single quotes are added with the string into the table, so the record in the database looks like this:

```
'Dan'    12    7
```

Has anybody come across this problem before, or am I doing something drastically wrong which I can't see?

Answer (score 3):

```
$data['questionId'] = $question['id'];
$data['answerText'] = $question->answer;
```

These two lines seem questionable to me. First line, $question is an array and onto the second line, question is an object getting the property answer?! Are you sure you do not get any php error in the log?

Also, in the active record [insert](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) documentation, it is stated very clearly **Note: All values are escaped automatically producing safer queries.** You should really find out if you have did any modification because from the question, there is not much to guess from. I think you should quote using the library [escape function](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html) rather than quote yourself. Something like

```
$insert = array(
      'answerText' => $this->db->escape_str(data['answerText']),
      'responseId' => $data['responseId'],
      'questionId' => $data['questionId']
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the answer. The reason that the code is like that is because the id is an attribute of question and the answer is child element of question in the XML. It is correct. I actually fixed it like this:

```
$insert = array(
        'answerText' => (string)$data['answerText'], // Needed to declare it was a string 
        'responseId' => $data['responseId'],
        'questionId' => $data['questionId']
    );
```

It seems like a hack to me, but it worked. The thing is, I have used this insert array in other parts of the project for inserting strings without this declaration and it works fine. I am not sure why in this case it didn't.

Comment: Isn't that essentially the same as what Jasonw suggested?

Comment: Its not the same though, is it?

Comment: It's just that I noticed you did not _accept_ Jasonw's answer, although it looks like what you ended up with is fundamentally what Jasonw suggested. But perhaps I am missing a key difference. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @jogojapan Judge from the OP's answer, it looks to me that the project code can be spaghetti or even lack of understanding but aim to make it work based on the result of the system display. I will keep my finger cross.

Comment: @jogojapan It was an oversight on my part. I'm a new user of the site and wasn't aware of the protocols. Duly accepted.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Parsed XML requires typecasting, otherwise active record gets (quite bizarrely) confused